# Where to put my IF statements/cases/general SQL Stoogery

Tags: sql, if-statement, ms-access, case

Im a bit of an SQL novice working with an old MS Access database. Im trying to pull some data out of it and I think I have a good start but thought I'd try to tap some expertise. Below is my query so far, its looking alright but could use some refinement.

```
TRANSFORM Avg(Trees.Dbh) AS Dbh
SELECT Trees.PlotNo, Trees.[Tree#], Trees.SP, First(Trees.CrownCls) AS InitialCrownCls, First(Trees.LCR) AS InitialLCR
FROM Trees
WHERE (((Trees.PlotNo) In ('01-03','02-03','02-04','03-05','03-06','03-07','04-04','04-05','04-06','04-07','05-04','05-06','05-07','06-04')))
GROUP BY Trees.PlotNo, Trees.[Tree#], Trees.SP
ORDER BY Trees.Year
PIVOT Trees.Year;
```

First off, I'm not too sure about the 'Transform' Statement to start it off, I built the query from scratch to get the data I was after but used the 'Design' UI (if you're familiar with access) to make the pivot table, and the only way I could get it to work was if I averaged the DBH values (but its an average of one record so its fine I guess?)

Second, I'm not sure if 'first' is doing what I want. Measurements of trees are taken every five years, I want the DBH of each year but only the initial measurement of LCR/CrownClass. Additionally, the data set starts in the 60 but individual tree records might not appear until later. First seems to work but I'm a bit of a doofus when it comes to reading documentation so please correct me if I'm in the wrong.

However, the real meat of my post is Case/If statements: this data goes back to 60s and has some 'implied' decimals due to only being able to work in integers. so before 1989 a value of 244 is really 24.4. **So how would I go about dividing all records >=1989 by 10**

I also need to swap out the Crown Class coded values to something with meaning, I think its a case thing, and answering the above question should get me on the path to success. Thanks for reading and any help would be duly appreciated.

Requested edit: Sample data

[Table design of sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4IMDL.png)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S1LO4.png)
(sort of, but general idea)

So in scrounging that up, I noticed something that makes me think I'm not nearly as close to ironing this out as I hoped. in the Output table, the selected record shows the switch from integer to number fields, with 46.7 record. but that stuck out to me because there's no way there was an almost 4ft wide tree that was missed until then. Looking deeper it was not missed, but not returned by query until that year for some reason.

Comment: Edit question to show sample data and desired output as text tables. Access SQL does not support CASE, use IIf().

Comment: First() and Last() might not produce desired output. Tables do not have intrinsic order (records are 'marbles in a bucket'). If a sort is applied this will likely change what First() and Last() return.